# ASP Classic / CORS - Reporting no header when header for CORS is set

Tags: vbscript, cors, asp-classic

Apologies in advance, I'm new to CORS so might be something I am missing.

I'm attempting within my current localhost to setup a CORS from one localhost port to another localhost port. I've confirmed this is possible with two applications built in the same language/framework but I've encountered issues with two different languages / frameworks.

Currently, each localhost port is built like such-

Localhost1: React/.Net C#

Localhost2: React/.Net C#

Localhost3: ASP Classic

I am able to complete CORS between localhost 1 & 2 but I keep getting errors relating to the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with my headers when dealing with CORS between localhost2 & localhost 3.

Below is my current ASP Classic File I am trying to post data to, which is being used to confirm that the data is being sent -

```
<%
Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS"
Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"
Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"

If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "OPTIONS" then
    ' Handling preflight request
    Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
    Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS"
    Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"
    Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"
    Response.Status = 200
    Response.End
End If

' Check if it's a POST request
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    Dim requestData, id1
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set requestData = JSONParse(Request.Form("data")) ' Assuming "data" is the key where JSON is sent
    On Error Goto 0 ' Re-enable default error handling
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Handle JSON parsing errors
        Response.Status = 400 ' Bad Request
        Response.Write "Error while parsing JSON: " & Err.Description
        Response.End
    End If
    
    id1 = requestData("id1")
    
    If id1 = "" Or Not IsNumeric(id1) Then
        ' Invalid or missing data in the JSON payload
        Response.Status = 400 ' Bad Request
        Response.Write "Invalid or missing ID data"
        Response.End
    Else
        ' Respond with a confirmation message
        Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "application/json" ' Set appropriate Content-Type
        Response.Write "{ ""message"": ""Received the data successfully"" }" ' Respond with JSON confirming data receipt
        Response.End
    End If
Else
    ' Handling non-POST requests
    Response.Status = 405 ' Method Not Allowed
    Response.Write "Only POST requests are allowed"
    Response.End
End If
%>
```

Below is the message I get when looking at the devTools/issues within Chrome.

[image: Image of chrome devtools displaying header missing despite being on file]

What am I missing / how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Side note- Yes I know that * is a security issue, I am just using the wild card for testing purposes.

Comment: When it procs, does it throw an error message number?  Not chrome .. the script?   Also if the header doesn't exist, import the values you need to create it perhaps?

Comment: So start checking each if/then to see if its true , such as :If IF Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" add a response.write that says "yep posted<br>" and then if that works, keep working each if/then to see if its actually doing what you think it is .. then you will find what is missing likely.

Comment: Within my DevTools it isn't throwing a number but the message: `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/mainsite/arrival.asp' from origin 'https://localhost:44338' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` - When I check the issues within my devTools I see the img with the CORS Response header missing.

Comment: The header does exist within my arrival.asp file, as it is the first thing listed as per my post.

Comment: I see , oh one thing I am seeing is you have an http to https connection transfer, is that the security issue you were talking about?

Comment: Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept"

Here is a simple explanation about the addheader command ->
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_addheader.asp

Comment: No - the security issue I was referring to was using a '*' within the allow origin as it would allow all incoming traffic to POST. I've updated the code I have to use a HTTPS link instead of the HTTP but issues persists. I've checked the above w3schools link and I appear to be following the standard convention for setting up the headers as specified.

Comment: I see, well if it should be working and isn't we have to figure out why its not creating the header, so did you go through each of the steps adding a response.write message to confirm each step ran?  Then you can find which step MIGHT be missing or perhaps has an unexpected value such as Empty or something.  I wonder too have you tried the No CORS option and see what happens (im sure its not your desired out come) but always do tests to find the unexpected result.

Comment: Would check in IIS that you have `OPTIONS` selected as a recognised verb in the Classic ASP request handler. IIS might be responding with `405 Method Not Allowed` when the browser makes the pre-flight request.

Comment: @SpencerAl would appreciate some feedback on the answer provided. The accepted solution is using a sledgehammer to hammer in a nail and a lot of that is based on assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issues.

I had to setup the CORS headers within my HTTP Headers section within IIS to allow the to allow the CORS to post to my localhost rather than setup the details within a singular file of the ASP classic code.

I believe this is due to being a server level issues rather than a code related issue.

Comment: That will bypass the need for ASP to handle the headers as IIS will return the headers earlier in the pipeline. Glad that worked for you. If you had wanted control over the headers in the ASP page though adding the `OPTIONS` verb to the Request Restrictions in the ASP ISAPI Module would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen due to IIS short-circuiting the request before it reaches the ASP page.

By default the Classic ASP ISAPI Handler will only accept `GET`, `HEAD` and `POST` as valid HTTP verbs and using other verbs like `OPTIONS` will result in an HTTP status response of `405 Method Not Allowed`. To use `OPTIONS` you will need to edit the HTTP Handler for the ASPClassic IsapiModule in the Handler Mappings for the Classic ASP Website in IIS (see image below)

[image: Handler Mappings - Request Restrictions]

and add `OPTIONS` to the comma-delimited list of allowed verbs.